# How to remove error when pathprovider search an empty file in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I use pathprovider to search a video I saved. I use a bottom app bar and pageview to slide between page, and when I change page and build the widget , my inistat() search in a folder a file, but if there isn't file I have graphic error, and it's uggly when I change page, I have a quick error screen. How can remove this error screen ?[image]

here is where I think is the problem:

```
  Future<String> startVideoRecording() async {
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(            //Here is the regex fonction to extract long, lat
      r"(^\S*)",
    );

    var match = regExp.firstMatch("$_currentDate");
    _currentDate_modify = match.group(1);

    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print('file:${extDir.path}/Movies/$_currentDate_modify.mp4');
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(

        'file:${extDir.path}/Movies/$_currentDate_modify.mp4'
    )

      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {

        });
      });


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default value or default widget to show while the async function completes..

```
String variable;
```

To set default value

```
variable??'default value'
```

To set a default widget, I just used an empty container

```
variable!=null?Your_Widget():Container()
```